# How to show legends verticaly using ParametricPlot and Show

Tags: plotting, legending

I am trying to combine 10 different plots using `Show`. My code has the following form

```
p1 = ParametricPlot[{f1[x], g1[x]}, x]
p2 = ParametricPlot[{f2[x], g2[x]}, x]
. 
.
.
p10 = ParametricPlot[{f10[x], g10[x]}, x]
Show[p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10]
```

I want legends to appear vertically, on the right side of the plot. Since I am plotting 10 different curves, horizontal legends do not fit in a eps file.

The output is:

[image]

Comment: How are you constructing the legend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ParametricPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot.html) can handled multiple parametric curves. [`Show`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html) is not necessary unless you are combining different types of plots.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Table[{f[k][x], g[k][x]} = {k*Sin[x], k*Cos[x]}, {k, 1, 10}];

ParametricPlot[
 Evaluate[{f[#][x], g[#][x]} & /@ Range[10]], {x, 0, 2 Pi},
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]